# How can I aggregate Python/Pandas row data into a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following **Pandas** datafame:

```
residue  aa   residue
L37      N    2.0
L37      A    3.0
L37      M    4.0
L37      R    5.0
L38      N    12.0
L39      A    13.0
L40      M    14.0
L41      R    15.0
...
```

I am trying to re-orient the data such that it looks more like a 2D matrix:

```
     N     A     M     R
L37  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
L38  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0
...
```

The only way I can think to to this is to create a 2D array a loop over each line. It seems like Pandas might have a better way though, so I am looking for any pointers that someone could help me with.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for **using Pandas to convert the "row-based" data to "matrix-based" data?**

Comment: Just rename the second `residue` column and use `df.pivot_table('residue.1', 'aa',  'residue', fill_value=0)` or if you can't rename the column, use `df.pivot_table(df.columns[2], df.columns[0], df.columns[1], fill_value=0)`

Comment: Or maybe `df.pivot(index='residue', columns='aa', values='residue.1')`